# Pdf links throwing 500 error after firewall update

Tags: asp.net, pdf, iis, firewall

I'm using ASP.NET VB Web Forms Framework 4 for an old website that hosts a variety of content. We have had a recent firewall update on the server that enforced some stricter policies. All content on the website is still accessible including jpegs, pngs, docs and xlsx however PDF files are now throwing a 500 Error whenever you attempt to access them; see image for the 'Detailed Error' page from Chrome.

I've followed the things to try; NTFS permissions are unchanged from before firewall change, request is mapped to a managed handler and .NET Extensibility is installed but as far as I'm aware none of the features in IIS have been changed just a firewall migration. The tracing rule instructions provided by Microsoft are unclear and I'm not sure how I would implement this to trace the actual error.

The IIS log file throws something similar to this for pdfs;

```
2023-04-18 11:13:52 192.168.#.# GET /pdfs/HE+Strategic+Plan+2013-14+-+2016-17.pdf - 443 - IP Address Mozilla/5.0+(Linux;+Android+6.0.1;+Nexus+5X+Build/MMB29P)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/112.0.5615.49+Mobile+Safari/537.36+(compatible;+Googlebot/2.1;++http://www.google.com/bot.html) - 500 0 1001 118
```

Port 443 is open for https connections for other file types just not the DocumentHandler.

I've followed this page https://www.asptricks.net/2015/06/error-code-0x800703e9-http-error-5000.html with no luck.

Any suggestions for what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a similar issue with this, I solved it by deleting the Handler Mapping from IIS and added I'm not sure why this worked but it has.